# Program stops when running OpenCL

Tags: multithreading, opencl, knn

The OpenCL code is as followed:

```
typedef struct {
    float record[8];
    float dis;
    int t_class;
}node;

float Dist ( __global float * a , __global float * b , int width ) {
    float rst = 0;

    for (int i =0; i < width; i++){
        rst += (a[i] - b[i])*(a[i] - b[i]);
    }

    return sqrt(rst);
}


__kernel void ex_knn ( __global node * in_data , __global node * in_data_copy, int num_record , int num_feature, __global float * new_point , int k , __global node * rst )
{
    int idx = get_global_id(0);

    for(int i=0;i<4177;i++){
        in_data_copy[idx*4177 + i] = in_data[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i < num_record; i++){
        in_data_copy [idx*4177 + i ]. dis = Dist ( in_data_copy [idx*4177 +  i ]. record , new_point , num_feature );
    }

    node tmp;
    for (int i=0; i< num_record-1;i++)
        for (int j =0; j<num_record-i-1; j++)
        {
            if ( in_data_copy [ idx*4177 + j ]. dis > in_data_copy [idx*4177 + j + 1 ]. dis )
            {
                tmp = in_data_copy [ idx*4177 + j ];
                in_data_copy [ idx*4177 + j ] = in_data_copy [ idx*4177 + j + 1 ];
                in_data_copy [ idx*4177 + j + 1 ] = tmp ;
            }
        }

    for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
        rst [ idx * k + i ] = in_data_copy [ idx*4177 + i ];

}
```

I found this code segment erroneous but I don't know why.
Basically it's a knn method with data set copies running on multiple threads.
in_data_copy is a global memory section for multiple data set copies. That means, each single thread has a data set copy. 
And then I do exhaustive knn method, calculate the distance, and sorting.

I know there might be race condition here, some threads might calculate the distances while some other threads might do the swapping. Yet these threads are dealing with different chunk of the 'in_data_copy', does that matter ?

When I ran the program, all the code before swapping ran correctly.
When come into the swapping, the OpenCL code stop somewhere and program exit. Have any idea about why this happen?

Comment: Please fix the code formatting in the question and  add the rest of the kernel while you are at it. A small code snippet taken out of context is completely unhelpful in understanding what might be going wrong.

Comment: Why isn't the j loop like this:  for (int j =0; j<i-1; j++)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't go out of bounds in `Dist()` and in `in_data_copy`, the structure alignment is very likely the problem. You need to align the structure to the next power of 2 size. Currently your structure size is 40 bytes, next power of 2 is 64 bytes. You can pad your structure by adding 6 4-byte element array in the top or 6x 4-byte members at the bottom. 2nd option could look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float record[8];
    float dis;
    int t_class;
    int pad1;
    int pad2;
    int pad3;
    int pad4;
    int pad5;
    int pad6;
}node;
```

Note: It is important to declare the structure from the widest type first down to the narrowest to avoid potential issues with unused spaces and different alignments on different devices.

Comment: Actually after add 6 pads into the structure, the results get wrong even adding `if (idx >=0 && idx<=0)`. By commenting out the swapping part, I could make sure other functions work correctly. The problem is highly possible with the swapping part. When it failed, it was pretty confused that the program would run extra longer time and exit before finish the kernel. Any idea about what might cause this ?

Comment: Did you pad it on both host and device side? Also check on the host if sizeof the struct is 64 bytes.

Comment: Yes, and the host side indicate it is 64 bytes now. And I guess the kernel return directly inside the for loop.

Comment: Can you post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If it's possible, it would be more convenient to send you the code to your email. But I could try to create one.

Comment: Also, did alignment problem would cause the kernel stop and return ?

Comment: I don't know how about alignment issues but from my experience for out of bound array access on one device it was working like everything was ok, on another was giving wrong results and on the 3rd device kernel was crashing. Many times the errors returned are misleading. I think you can expect anything really. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361274/how-to-set-the-right-alignment-for-an-opencl-array-of-structs) proper alignment fixed the issue. In your case that's probably similar issue plus it maybe something more.

Comment: An interesting fact would be the results is correct when I ported the same code to a machine with an AMD APU card. Previously I ran on a Nvidia Tesla card. I guess Nvidia runtime do something to throw an exception.